# Go To Find Combo Open File Errors in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

While the Go To Find Combo control is my #1 favorite thing about Visual Studio, it has some annoying problems when trying to use "of" to open files:

1. It auto completes on period, but some built-in project folders have spaces in them.  In particular projects have a "Web References" folder that makes it really difficult to get to any "web.config" file.
2. It doesn't always show all files of a certain name; this is the case with a file that is our base class for all of our web pages.  It also has a couple of classes that begin with the exact same name as the class - ie XPage and XPageBanner.  Not sure if either of these are related.
3. Code in front classes show up with the solution name in parenthesis, and are auto-completed to "Filename.aspx (Solution" (with the quotes).  IF I try to open them, I get an error, which googling doesn't help.  "The Operation Could Not Be Completed.  The system could not find the file specified."

Does anyone know how to resolve any of these?